I get root@DESKTOP- TDKVO1R :~# after an do-release-upgrade. Why?
After I run the do-release-update command in ubuntu this "root@DESKTOP- TDKVO1R :~#" command line appears and it is never ending

Most lilkely, the update has broken your GUI

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. This may help you fix your system back to normal

You've provided no specifics as to what you were using, and what you release-upgraded to, so we'd mostly be guessing.  If you were using 22.04 & just release-upgraded to 24.04 then duplicate link by @ArchismanPanigrahi would almost certainly apply; but you've provided no real specifics for us to know.
